# Rotate drawable from a specific "rotation point"

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I have an image, a simple black rectangle. I want to be able to rotate the image from a specific *rotation point* in it, with a certain amount of degrees provided by the user in a textbox(all this done, keeping the location intact).

[illustration of "rotation point"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIwLb.png)

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` has 2 fields that keep coordinates of a pivot point. In your case, only one of them needs to change and that is X coordinate. Here is the working example:

```
imageView.setPivotX(0);
imageView.setRotation(DEGREES);
```